# Multiple instances of SQL Server for connection vs connectionless?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-connection

Consider that I have two databases. If I want one of them to be connected to a TCP/IP protocol and one of them I don't want connected, do I need to open up two separate instances of SQL Server or would it be possible with the only one instance. How would I manage to separate the permissions in the latter case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network configuration is at the instance level.  So if you really need network isolation (ie regular SQL Server security is not good enough), you need a second instance.